# multiple swing worker for an application with various button

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, concurrency

supposing I have an application with various buttons.every button execute a different task.One opens a file, another prints some information and so on.I have to implement a different object that extends swingworker class for every button presents in my applation?

Comment: -1, instead of continually asking questions why don't you actually try it? Then if you have problems you can post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each action requires a background thread, then yes, I'd use a different SwingWorker for each one. No big deal though. What is the issue that you're having?